# Alter cmd-tab behaviour on OSX to group Parallels applications?

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, application-switcher

When running a Parallels virtual machine (i.e. Windows 7), cmd-tab behaves as the Parallels icon showing the list of virtual machines (which can be closed) and a separate icon for each open Windows application.

It would improve my productivity for Windows to appear as a single icon that just switches to whatever is open on my Windows VM. How do I do this?

I am running OSX 10.9 and Parallels 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must deselect the "Share Windows applications with Mac" option in the Applications pane of your VM's configuration.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try (ctrl - left alt - tab) & (right alt - tab) should do the trick…

Well it does it using VMware where you can also change inside "**VMWare**" menu "**Preferences…** "**Keyboard & Mouse**" pane the key mappings to give priority either to the VM or the host. I don't see why it wouldn't be the same with Parallels…